# NVDA precedes text with "blank" when using jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, screen-readers, nvda

When the `.datepicker()` is initiated and the user shifts between dates using the

```
ctrl+left
ctrl+right
ctrl+up
ctrl+down
```

the screen reader works perfectly only when either <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd> combo is used.

However, when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> combo is used, NVDA reads `"blank"` and then the date selection.

So, in summary, output when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> key:

```
21 February, 2016
14 February, 2016
```

However, when using ctrl+left/ctrl+right key:

```
blank 20 February, 2016
blank 22 February, 2016
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening and how to overcome this?

Here is the fiddle to see it an action: [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/f118d36d/)

Comment: Unable to replicate this in FireFox. What browser are you using?

Comment: That's strange. I tested on Firefox, latest version.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue in 1.12.1?

Comment: @Twisty No idea. I found a solution and delivered it to the concerned party. Haven't heard back from them since...